# math operation on lists in python

Tags: python, list, addition, element

Suppose I have an array `[2, 10, 6, 3]`. Suppose I want to do some processing which as the result list will be `[0, 2, 12, 18]`. It's not a puzzle I'm just adding the elements of list and put the result in a new list with the same size, but the 1st element must set into zero. How can I implement this in line in python? I have tried:

```
n = reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y + x[-1]], list1, [0])
```

but the result list is `[0, 2, 12, 18, 21]` which is not the desired result due to the last element's existence.

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the list:

```
>>> list1=[2,10,6,3]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y + x[-1]], list1[:-1], [0]) 
[0, 2, 12, 18]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use numpy, try `numpy.cumsum` (cumulative sum):

```
import numpy as np
np.cumsum([2, 10, 6, 3])
```

You can then mess with the resulting list to get what you want:

```
a = np.cumsum([2, 10, 6, 3])
[0] + a[:-1].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be too clever; here's a simple loop:

```
out = []
cs = 0
for v in list1:
    out.append(cs)
    cs += v
```